# Spring Message Listener - Connection Refresh

Tags: spring, jboss, jms, ibm-mq

We have implemented a message listener with spring and the container configurations looks like below

```
    <bean id="customContainer"
        class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="${jms.customContainer.concurrentconsumers}" />
        <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="${jms.customContainer.maxconcurrentconsumers}" />
        <property name="errorHandler" ref="errorHandler" />
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsQueueConnectionFactory" />
        <property name="destination" ref="listenerQueue" />
        <property name="messageListener" ref="customContainerListener" />
        <property name="receiveTimeout" value="1" />
        <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true" />
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="txManager" />
    </bean>
```

Its deployed in Jboss and the server log shows the below connection refresh message frequently.

```
org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer] (customContainer-3849) Successfully refreshed JMS Connection
```

It's been reported a high MSU/MIPS utilization at mainframe side where the WebSphere MQ is hosted. Could this be a reason to cause frequent MQ GET calls and increase in utilization?

We haven't specified the message Reply To explicitly, will this be causing a reply to attempt to queue every time? Also the receive timeout is set to 1 ms, does that mean it will be actively polling the queue in every 1 ms? Could someone please explain the concept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` implements polling of the queue.  This means that it issues a GET with a wait of the `receiveTimeout`.  If you have a `receiveTimeout` of 1ms, that means that every GET call will return after 1ms if no message is on the queue and another GET call will be made.  This would appear to the queue manager as back to back GET calls.

Two options:

1. You can increase `receiveTimeout` to a higher number which will cause get with wait of the specified value, for example, get with wait of 60000 ms would only do a get every 1 minute or after a message hits the queue.  You still get messages off the queue as soon as they are PUT to the queue.
2. A slightly more efficient option if possible is to switch to the `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` which will use a native JMS async listener.  For IBM MQ this is implemented with the MQ callback functionality.  This means the listener registers the callback to the queue manager and the queue manager notifies the listener when new messages land on the queue, so there is no polling.

Comment: Thanks much. I was working around this issue for a while and  we have came across with an interesting issue. as we were relying on Hibnerate Transaction manager earlier, the recive time out was not in effect (There were no issues reported from Mainframe systems), but maintaining receive timeout at milliseconds and changing TX manager to JTA ran in to an issue of frequent GET calls - I beleive this turned on the actual receive timeout behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for the update.  Did you end up implementing a larger receiveTimeout or did you switch to a `SimpleMessageListenerContainer`?

Comment: Currently we increased the timeout to a larger value as a quick fix.

Answer (score 2):

Please see https://marketaylor.synology.me/?p=668

Note that the 'contributions' to the CPU consumption - which ultimately impacts the MSU charges are driven by several things that should be controlled.  The two biggest are:

1. The number of connects to/disconnects from the z/OS queue manager.  These verbs are the most costly in terms of CPU use in MQ, and should be used judiciously on z/OS because of the cost model. A client application written to connect once and do many MQ actions is going to impact the CPU consumption, but that tends to be predictable and is as they say 'a cost of doing business.'  A client application that connects, opens a queue, puts or gets a single message, then disconnects many, many times will drive up costs quickly ( we have seen instances of a 40% uplift in MSU charges in a single month).  The latter is called a poorly behaved application.
2. The use of Temporary Dynamic queues.  TD queues require a significant amount of overhead within the queue manager, as the queue infrastructure has to be built up for each new definition and then torn down when the queue is closed. This overhead can be avoided by using statically defined queues and retrieving messages via the correlation ID or message ID.
   Note that while both these issues are not unique to MQ on z/OS it is the licensing/charging model that makes all the difference.
   Good luck!

Comment: Good information on the z/OS end.    I didn't catch in the question that they were using temp dynamic queues or connecting and disconnecting?  The `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` does issue frequent GET calls by default at 1 second intervals and according to the OP they tuned this down to 1ms so much more frequently.

Comment: Hi JoshMc - I have observed default behavior by Spring clients do both those things (and drive up MLC on z/OS) that the only reason I mentioned it as a possible cause.  Often all I see is the end result - when people start shouting - not the code and environment settings that actually cause it (smile).  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the additional information.  You referenced Mark's blog, and he is probably much more familiar than I am with the low level details of the DMLC, but from what I understand it does connect and keep the queue open, the only problem was the default behavior is to repeatedly issue a get with 1000ms wait, and to top it off there was no easy way to tune that setting.  I'm sure other components of Spring may open/close connections and can use TDQs, and even in this case if the app was replying to the messages it receives it may open a new session to send that reply.

Comment: Some of this can be handled by using a `CachingConnectionFactory` to prevent the constant connect and disconnect cycle.

Comment: Thanks Carolyn. This seems more helpful from a tuning perspective. We do use static queues. As mentioned in JoshMC's reply looks like this receive timeout parameter is in action when we changed the TX manager from Hibnerate to JTA. With 1ms and Hibernate TX manage,thigs were normal and EPV showed minimal GET's.