# Spring Boot listener high CPU consumption on high throughput

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms, amazon-sqs, spring-jms

We have the following use case:

- System process feeds an SQS queue with a large number of message (about 140 000)
- Java Spring Boot micro-service `A` handles messages from SQS queue
- Micro-service `A` calls micro-service `B` on each message and then does business processes

When everything works fine each message is processed in about 1000ms, but when micro-service `B` is down the message is processed in about 10ms because we have no other processes to do. When that happens micro-service `A` unstack the queue very quickly, but the CPU usage of the EC2 instance spike to 100%.

To test it we have run our process, shutdown the micro-service `B` during about 30min and then restart micro-service `B`. We took screenshots of CPU usage, response time, and throughput during this test.

We have set up the concurrent number of message processed to 4 in the `DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory` and use the Spring Boot `@JmsListener` annotation to handle SQS messages.

Messages are mapped through a jackson message converter.

I attached below some images helping understand our issue and the use case.

- A NewRelic screenshot showing elapsed time and throughput of the listener:
  [image]
- an AWS screenshot of the CPU usage on the EC2 instance:
  [image]
- an SQS screenshot of the number of message in the queue (to show it's unstacking quickly):
  [image]
- a diagram to explain the test and use case:
  [image]

Any idea why the CPU spike to 100% when message are handled very quickly?

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72222616/high-cpu-usage-from-the-spring-defaultmessagelistenercontainer-thread
or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63604061/spring-message-listener-connection-refresh
help you

Comment: Why *wouldn't* the CPU spike when messages are being dispatched and consumed quickly? That work isn't free.

Comment: @JustinBertram doesn't seems logical to me, I have the same number of concurrent listener in both case. The queue is unstacked fastly because the listener use less time to compute each message when our business process is KO

Comment: @FaramarzAfzali thanks for the links, I already tried to update some of the given properties  with no luck so far.
I will retest it later on just to be sure

Comment: It seems plausible to me that the SQS client and any pre-delivery message processing tasks used by your Spring `@JmsListener` are taking up additional CPU time as the consumption rate increases. As noted previously, that work isn't free. You should gather thread-dumps from your application when the CPU spikes to see what the application is actually doing during that time.

Comment: @JustinBertram yes it's seems to be exactly that. 
We solved it by adding a rateLimiter into the JMSListener in order to limit the consumption rate when our service B goes down.